# JQuery: a slider with 3 inputs possible?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I wanna create a slider with 3 inputs. I have made a lot of research but can't find more than a slider with 2 inputs :/

Here is the code: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

How can I create a 3 input slider ? I want to have a slider that move with the 3 inputs. For example, if the input1 is at 0, input2 at 50 and input3 at 100 and the max value is 100. If i put the input2 at 25, the input2-input1 is going to get low and input3-input2 is going to get high.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The slider you've shown is a range input.  Can you give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: I try to make a drawing: https://ibb.co/ksxieT

Comment: are you trying to say you want to make a drag slider with 3 handles?

Comment: please select the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand you are looking for 3 drag handles on a slider if i am not wrong you can do that like below

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100000,
  values: [0, 50000, 100000],
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Oh thank ! Just some questions: how do I have the lentgh between 2 inputs ? Also, how can input1 never have a value higher than input2 ?

Comment: that's a separate question but you have several events that you can use like `slide`, `stop`,`step` etc look in the [`DOCS`](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) @Lazare

Comment: I have other question about this, I create a new topic cause it's more specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662561/know-the-value-between-2-inputs-slider-jquery