# Know the value between 2 inputs slider jquery

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have made this question to create a slider with 2/3 inputs.
Here is the link: [JQuery: a slider with 3 inputs possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488419/jquery-a-slider-with-3-inputs-possible)

How can I get the value between all of 2 choosen inputs ?

Code:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100000,
  values: [0, 50000, 100000],
});

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here is the html part:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: you should probably add the code here by creating a small demo of your current code , otherwise it is likely to be closed due to being un-clear.

Comment: I still use the code from the past question you respond to me link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488419/jquery-a-slider-with-3-inputs-possible

Comment: yes i know but its not only me who knows it there are other people who can help you too and it makes easier for them if the code is added here , you just need to copy paste

Comment: Ok give me a second. Drawing talk more than word here is what I wanna know: https://media1.giphy.com/media/1zR9xAhsPacfAQi5ny/giphy.gif

Comment: please help me !

Comment: the image you have provided what is written in the last line for the value of  `c` ?

Comment: for example if i say that `slider1 is on 1` , `slider 2 is on 100` and `slider 3 is on 1000` what would be the values for `a`,`b` and `c` ?

Comment: added an answer

Comment: Add it ;) Thx you ! Could you help me with this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716970/export-html-val-to-python-using-flask

Comment: :) would have , but i dont work with python

Comment: Oh ok ! No prob ;) Thx you for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `slide` event to detect the values of the sliders and assign them respectively from the given picture

[image]

i understand that if we have 3 sliders x,y and z then

```
a=x;

b=x-y;

c=z-y;
```

You can get the slider values from the `ui` object passed in the `slide( event, ui )` event, which has the `ui.values` array holding the value of all the slider handle's current position, see a demo below

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100000,
  values: [0, 50000, 100000],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    //console.log(ui.values);
    let a = ui.values[0];
    let b = ui.values[1] - ui.values[0];
    let c = ui.values[2] - ui.values[1];

    $("#a").html(a);
    $("#b").html(b);
    $("#c").html(c);
    
    $("#x").html(ui.values[0]);
    $("#y").html(ui.values[1]);
    $("#z").html(ui.values[2]);
    
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>

<ul class="result">
  <li>A : <span id="a">0</span></li>
  <li>B : <span id="b">50000</span></li>
  <li>C : <span id="c">100000</span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="result">
  <li>X: <span id="x">0</span></li>
  <li>Y: <span id="y">50000</span></li>
  <li>Z: <span id="z">100000</span></li>
</ul>
```